# How does .lodash continue to work after I've deleted packages.json, package-lock.json, and node_modules?

Tags: node.js

I'm testing `node.js` on a Windows 10 system and I used `NPM` to install `lodash`.  My goal is to find out when it breaks.

My app consists of 3 lines of code.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
var testArray = _.uniq([12, 5, 5, 2, 8, 12]);
console.log(testArray);
```

**Attempt 1)** `package.json` contains this reference to lodash.

`"dependencies": {"lodash": "^4.17.4"}`

I deleted `package.json` typed app.js but it still ran fine.

**Attempt 2)** `package-lock.json` contains this reference to lodash.

`"dependencies": {"lodash": {"version": "4.17.4", "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.4.tgz", "integrity": "sha1-eCA6TRwyiuHYbcpkYONptX9AVa4="}`

I deleted this file, ran app.js and once again it still ran fine.

**Attempt 3)**  Time to pull out the big guns. I deleted the entire `node_modules` folder. I ran app.js and it still worked fine.  Holy cow is this thing invincible?

**Attempt 4)** I deleted the first line of code that references lodash.

`const _ = require('lodash');`

Finally app.js stopped working.

How does `lodash` continue to work after I've done steps 1 through 3?  Where is it stored or referenced after those are gone?  Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: `package.json` tells `npm` what to install.  It isn't actually the installation.  These libraries will be installed to a folder, likely named `node_modules`.  When you call `require('lodash')`, you are telling `node` to load `lodash` (via CommonJS).

Comment: Step 1 and 2 don't matter. Step 4, of course it would break. For step 3, I believe you have lodash installed in a parent directory. Node follows upwards until it finds one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lodash` is still working after you removed it from your local `node_modules`, it must be installed somewhere else (either globally, or on `NODE_PATH`, or up the directory hierarchy).

When `require` attempts to resolve a module, it first looks in your local directory for a `node_modules` folder. If it can't find it, it will look at the parent directory to try and find it. If it can't find it there, it will keep going all the way up the directory hierarchy.

Additionally, `require` will look for the module in all the paths listed in the `NODE_PATH` environment variable or in the following special locations:

- `$HOME/.node_modules`
- `$HOME/.node_libraries`
- `$PREFIX/lib/node`

Where `$HOME` is your home directory and `$PREFIX` is configured internally by Node.

Now, we probably don't want to search *every* possible folder where a module could be located, so Node has the useful `require.resolve` that prints the location where it found a module. Note that it does not load the module -- it just prints the location where it was found.

In your case, try this:

```
console.log( require.resolve('lodash') ); // location where lodash was found
```

If you're interested in the actual (pseudocode) algorithm that `require` uses to resolve modules, you can [view it here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

Comment: 100% pure gold!  Thanks so much!  I ran `console.log( require.resolve('lodash') );` and somehow I had a `node_modules` folder at the root of my c drive.  I checked and it had 345 modules.  I wonder if that was put there by default when I installed `node.js`.

Comment: @DR01D probably you ran `npm install package` when on `c:\`

Comment: Interesting!  Can I delete the `node_modules` folder at the root of my c drive?  If I need it I'll keep it.  But otherwise I'd rather delete it to get a better feel for how a 'clean' `node.js` install works because I'm learning.